# ¿Como compartir una indicación de mi sitio y que se habrá en el Google Maps igual?

Tags: google-maps

Hola! ¿Como podría compartir la indicación? Tengo mi sitio con el mapa de Google Maps y el [servicio de Indicaciones](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=es-419). Entonces, quisiera que el usuario al generar una indicación tenga la opción de compartir un link para abrir la misma indicación pero en el Google Maps. Por ejemplo, que al generar una indicación en mi sitio del lugar X hasta el lugar Y, el link abra el mapa de Google con las mismas indicaciones de los lugares X y Y.

Aqui un ejemplo de una indicación compartida desde Google: [link](https://www.google.co.ve/maps/dir/El+Parche,+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/25+de+Mayo,+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/@-35.7134192,-60.5668638,10z/am=t/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x95be3d1b352ca965:0x8b485751a259c3b6!2m2!1d-60.2464767!2d-35.870284!1m5!1m1!1s0x95be67dcdf723a35:0x4b3099e60f7968cd!2m2!1d-60.3037323!2d-35.5123971?hl=es)

Comment: Hola Jonathan,  agrega tu código o lo que has intentado. Te sugiero realices el [tour] para conocer como funciona el sitio no olvides revisar [ask].

Comment: No tengo código aún. Solo quisiera como un ejemplo de un sitio que haga lo mismo o como podría sacar la dirección...  Para así hacer el código

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pides indicaciones a google.maps.api haciendo, por ejemplo:

```js
function initMap() {

        var theOrigin = {
                lat: -33.45,
                lng: -70.68
            },
            theDestination = {
                lat: -33.41,
                lng: -70.57
            };


        //Generamos el mapa que muestre y cual será el punto central
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: (theOrigin.lat + theDestination.lat) / 2,
                lng: (theOrigin.lng + theDestination.lng) / 2
            },
            zoom: 12
        });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        //Generamos el marcadores para señalar una posición
        var markerOrigen = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: theOrigin,
            title: "Origen"
        });
        markerOrigen.setMap(map);
        var markerDestino = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: theDestination,
            title: "Destino"
        });
        markerDestino.setMap(map);

        directionsService.route({
            origin: theOrigin,
            destination: theDestination,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
#map {
 height:300px;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>

 
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="map"></div>
```

Verás que el origen y destino se han definido como:

```
    var theOrigin = {
            lat: -33.45,
            lng: -70.68
        },
        theDestination = {
            lat: -33.41,
            lng: -70.57
        };
```

Y por tanto tu petición de ruta (conduciendo) es:

```
directionsService.route({
        origin: theOrigin,
        destination: theDestination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
```

Esto debiese arrojar lo mismo que la siguiente url:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=-33.45,-70.68&destination=-33.41,-70.57&travelmode=driving

Simplemente pones el origen como `origin=<lat>,<lng>` y lo mismo para el destino.